# In Flask, how can I generate a dynamic URL from form data?

Tags: python, flask

In html, I have a form consisting of three radio button

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="post">   
     <input type="radio" name="option" value="banana"> Banana<br>
     <input type="radio" name="option" value="apple">apple<br>
     <input type="radio" name="option" value="peach"> peach<br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Text">
 </form>
```

In my app.py, I have the method defined for this:

```
    @app.route('/result/<fruit>', methods=['POST'])
    def handle_data(fruit):
        fruit = request.form['option']
        return render_template("result.html",fruit = fruit)
```

What I wanna do was redirecting from my current html file to a new URL, and the new URL is corresponding to which radio button I click. For example, if I click "apple" and hit the "submit text" button, I will be redirected to "/result/apple".

I did that in the way above, it gives me a server error. What did I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do dynamic URLs **OR** parse form data, you don't need to do both. In this case, I would only use the result URL without the dynamic URL with  because your template is expecting your dynamic URL in url_for to be completed. You can still use dynamic URLs, but I believe you would need to add some JavaScript to populate the URL as you click the submit button. Since the template is being rendered before you select a fruit, it doesn't know to pass a fruit at the end of your URL, thus your request would only go to /result/ instead of /result/apple if you submit apple.

```
@app.route('/result',methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
  fruit = request.form.get["option"]
  return render_template("result.html",fruit=fruit)
```